# OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000000; from generating a road map with coordinates using openstreetmap

Tags: python, pandas, openstreetmap, geopandas, osmnx

I am attempting to build a class that takes n random coordinate locations as input and creates a rectangle out of the northmost, eastmost, southmost, and westmost location. Then, it makes a request to openstreetmap to get the road network for that square and outputs the road network. Oddly enough, I got the class working with some data I took from an osm building element but it doesn't work with random coordinates. I get an OSError that looks like it has something to do with memory when the coordinates are random.

I'll start off here by showing you the random coordinates I generated, then the second class that throws the error. After that, I'll show you the error and then wrap up by showing you the working sample data with the correct output.

My random generated coordinates:

```
test = random_points(center, dist, n_points)
test.coords()

[(33.340752778646106, -119.600891577953),
 (41.01313723337449, -113.67789597461876),
 (53.34876838098478, -117.17129721590447),
 (27.64352459280383, -120.28660075024402),
 (24.921452668352913, -115.92740822888817),
 (31.829617502461304, -129.55182219699446),
 (48.86093573506412, -111.81760120881916),
 (40.46484579463828, -109.5822093899759),
 (42.32775994703087, -119.25567193618849),
 (44.84794837019382, -126.02873444605405)]
```

Next up, I convert these coordinates into a polygon and tried getting the road network:
(I'm really new to classes so please forgive me if this is poorly written)

```
import geopandas as gpd
import osmnx as ox
import shapely
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

class target_map():
    
    def __init__(self, location_list):
        """
        This class is used to connect an list of [(lat, lon), ...]
        pairs to a map of the physical network of roads for the location.
        
        param:  location_list is a list containing coordinate pairs 
                [(lat, lon), ...] pertaining to target locations.
                
        self.bbox() produces the boundaries of the maximum north, south, 
        east, and west coordinates
        
        self.polygon() produces the graphic representation (polygon obj)
        from self.bbox()
        
        self.graph() produces the graph object of the road network that 
        falls within self.bbox()

        self.gdf() produces a GeoDataFrame (nodes, edges) for self.graph()

        self.nearest_nodes() produces a list of coordinates corresponding to 
        the closest node on the graph, effectively mapping the input coordinate  
        list to the road network.
        """       
        # Creates generators for the coordinates, individually and paired
        self.__coord_list = [(lat, lon) for (lat, lon) in location_list]
        self.__latitudes = [lat for (lat, lon) in self.__coord_list]
        self.__longitudes = [lon for (lat, lon) in self.__coord_list]
        
        # Produces tuple pairs of (index for max value, max value) for each coordinate direction
        self.__northmost = (self.__latitudes.index(max(self.__latitudes)), max(self.__latitudes))
        self.__eastmost = (self.__longitudes.index(max(self.__longitudes)), max(self.__longitudes))
        self.__southmost = (self.__latitudes.index(min(self.__latitudes)), min(self.__latitudes))
        self.__westmost = (self.__longitudes.index(min(self.__longitudes)), min(self.__longitudes))
        
        # Produces the coordinate pairs for each target that is most in each coordinate direction
        self.__northcoord = self.__coord_list[self.__northmost[0]]
        self.__eastcoord = self.__coord_list[self.__eastmost[0]]
        self.__southcoord = self.__coord_list[self.__southmost[0]]
        self.__westcoord = self.__coord_list[self.__westmost[0]]
        
        # Produces a boundary box, containing each target
        self.__bbox = (self.__northcoord, self.__eastcoord, self.__southcoord, self.__westcoord)    
 

    # Returns the barrier box
    def bbox(self):
        return (self.__northmost, self.__southmost, self.__eastmost, self.__westmost)

    
    # Returns a polygon shape from the barrier box
    def polygon(self):
        self.__polygon = Polygon(self.__bbox)
        return self.__polygon
    
    
    # Returns the graph object of the street network associated with the coordinates
    def graph(self):
        
        # Creates polygon if not already
        try:
            self.__polygon
        except AttributeError:
            self.polygon()
            
        # Produces a graph object of the street network associated with the coordinates
        try:
            self.__G
        except AttributeError:
            self.__G = ox.graph.graph_from_polygon(self.__polygon, network_type='drive_service')
        
        return self.__G

    
    # Returns the GeoDataFrame
    def gdf(self):
        
        # Creates graph if not already
        try:
            self.__G
        except AttributeError:
            self.graph()
            
        # Produces a GeoDataFrame from the box of north, east, south, and westmost coordinate pairs
        try:
            self.__edges, self.__nodes
        except AttributeError:
            self.__edges, self.__nodes = ox.graph_to_gdfs(self.__G, nodes=True, edges=True)
        
        return (self.__edges, self.__nodes)

    
    # Returns the nodes corresponding to the input coordinate list
    def nearest_nodes(self):
        
        # Creates graph if not already
        try:
            self.__G
        except AttributeError:
            self.graph()
        
        # Connects the coordinates the closest points on the graph
        try:
            self.__nearest_nodes
        except AttributeError:
            self.__nearest_nodes = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(self.__G, self.__latitudes, self.__longitudes, return_dist=True)
        
        return self.__nearest_nodes
```

Now when I try to run this and get my roads, this is what comes back:

```
target_map(test.coords()).graph()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [957], in target_map.graph(self)
     68 try:
---> 69     self.__G
     70 except AttributeError:

AttributeError: 'target_map' object has no attribute '_target_map__G'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1002], in <module>
----> 1 target_map(test.coords()).graph()

Input In [957], in target_map.graph(self)
     69     self.__G
     70 except AttributeError:
---> 71     self.__G = ox.graph.graph_from_polygon(self.__polygon, network_type='drive_service')
     73 return self.__G

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\osmnx\graph.py:418, in graph_from_polygon(polygon, network_type, simplify, retain_all, truncate_by_edge, clean_periphery, custom_filter)
    416 buffer_dist = 500
    417 poly_proj, crs_utm = projection.project_geometry(polygon)
--> 418 poly_proj_buff = poly_proj.buffer(buffer_dist)
    419 poly_buff, _ = projection.project_geometry(poly_proj_buff, crs=crs_utm, to_latlong=True)
    421 # download the network data from OSM within buffered polygon

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\base.py:633, in BaseGeometry.buffer(self, distance, resolution, quadsegs, cap_style, join_style, mitre_limit, single_sided)
    631     self._lgeos.GEOSBufferParams_setQuadrantSegments(params, res)
    632     self._lgeos.GEOSBufferParams_setSingleSided(params, single_sided)
--> 633     return geom_factory(self.impl['buffer_with_params'](self, params, distance))
    635 if cap_style == CAP_STYLE.round and join_style == JOIN_STYLE.round:
    636     return geom_factory(self.impl['buffer'](self, distance, res))

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\shapely\topology.py:80, in UnaryTopologicalOp.__call__(self, this, *args)
     78 def __call__(self, this, *args):
     79     self._validate(this)
---> 80     return self.fn(this._geom, *args)

OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000000
```

Here's the baffling part, to me. I tried with some less random sample data I took from OSM. The class actually works when I use this:

```
x = target_map([(-121.8949266, 37.3361653), 
                (-121.894729, 37.3362566), 
                (-121.894746, 37.3362818), 
                (-121.8947639, 37.336307), 
                (-121.8948456, 37.3364211), 
                (-121.894977, 37.336598), 
                (-121.895215, 37.336488), 
                (-122.8949266, 38.3361653)])

x.graph()

<networkx.classes.multidigraph.MultiDiGraph at 0x1dcb02033a0>
```

There, output is correctly a MultiDiGraph object.

Answer (score 0):

This is not so odd in reality... The points that are crashing the environment are not valid.  WGS84/EPSG:4326 bounds: -180.0 -90.0, 180.0 90.0

I have coded a function `random_points()` to demonstrate.  If I switch off the validation that the center is valid, I crash my kernel with your code with and invalid set of random points.

```
import numpy as np


def random_points(center, dist, n_points, test_inputs=True):
    if test_inputs:
        assert (
            center[0] >= -180
            and center[0] <= 180
            and center[1] >= -90
            and center[1] <= 90
        ), "invalid point"
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[shapely.geometry.Point(center)], crs="epsg:4326")
    try:
        gdf = gdf.to_crs(gdf.estimate_utm_crs()).buffer(dist).to_crs(gdf.crs)
    except RuntimeError as e:
        if str(e) == "Unable to determine UTM CRS":
            gdf = gdf.buffer(.2)
        else:
            raise
    return [
        p
        for p in zip(
            np.random.choice(
                np.linspace(*gdf.total_bounds[[0, 2]], n_points * 10), n_points
            ),
            np.random.choice(
                np.linspace(*gdf.total_bounds[[1, 3]], n_points * 10), n_points
            ),
        )
    ]


target_map(random_points((-121.894729, 37.3362566), 500, 6)).graph()
try:
    target_map(random_points((41.01313723337449, -113.67789597461876), 500, 8)).graph()
except AssertionError as e:
    print(e)
# next line will crash my kernal...
target_map(random_points((41.01313723337449, -113.67789597461876), 500, 8, test_inputs=False)).graph()
```